# Give access to my application to read/write a file on var/www

Tags: linux, file, server

In my application, I need to write a file.json in /myserver/home/www/var/myApplicationFolder/file.json but it does not work. (there is no problem in the code as it has already been tested)
I think it because of the root permission .
What should I do?

Comment: Try `chmod` for permissions.

Comment: chmod or chown?
More details please.. I'm newbie to linux

Comment: it's `chmod 755 file.json`

Comment: the file still unwrittable without using sudo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you'd like any account on the server to be able to write to this folder then run:

```
sudo chmod 777 /myserver/home/www/var/myApplicationFolder/
```

or if you'd just like it to be able to write to that specific file:

```
sudo chmod 777 /myserver/home/www/var/myApplicationFolder/file.json
```

The `chmod` command takes 3 numbers which correspond to the permissions that the owner, people in the group, and everyone else gets respectively. The issue with the older answer was that they where giving the owner all the permissions (the first 7), but no giving any permissions to anyone else (the second and third 5).

Answer (score -2):

In the terminal run the command:

```
sudo chmod 755 /myserver/home/www/var/myApplicationFolder/
```

it should work.

Comment: the file still unwrittable without using sudo